# Как решить проблему с кодировкой для корректного отображения в базе данных и на сайте?

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, utf-8

Если зарегистрироваться через сайт, то информация на русском в базу данных не попадает(пустые поля). а если к кодировке в файле подключения(все файлы в кодировке UTF8 без BOM и сам файл подключения к базе данных) добавить:

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'cp1251'");

то все замечательно добавляется
НО возникает дургая проблема
Из базы данных информация(на русском) на сайт выводиться некорректно вот так- �����.
Что делать? 
P.S. я понимаю что вопрос с кодировкой всем надоел, но все же)

Comment: Кодировка в поле таблицы бд и в  SET CHARACTER должны быть одинаковы. Для UTF-8  попробуйте запрос 'SET NAMES utf8'  ( именно utf8 без черточки)

Comment: все пробую везде utf8, но данные(русский текст) которые вношу через сайт в базе данных пустые поля(((

Comment: то есть в базе везде utf-8, на сайте кодировка utf-8 и не работает? должно

Comment: Везде. Meta UTF8 сами файлы в UTF8 подключение к базе тоже прописала UTF8 и сами таблицы и база данных UTF8, какие ещё могут быть варианты?

Comment: Надо локализовать проблему, ошибка именно при сохранении в бд? То есть сделать скрипт в кодировке utf-8 и в нем сохранить в БД, будет нормально сохраняться? Английские буквы будут сохраняться?

Comment: Ошибка именно при сохранении в базу данных, Английские буквы сохраняются без проблем